# Shooting a Projectile using Cursor

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm making a game where you click to shoot a projectile that flies toward your cursor. However, I don't know how to go about making the projectile fly in the direction of the cursor. I tried finding the slope of the line like this...

```
 public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if(m.Msg == 0x0201)
            {
                Point MousePos = PointToClient(Form.MousePosition);

                slope = (MousePos.Y - aCharacter.Location.Y) / (MousePos.X - aCharacter.Location.X);
                aLaser.Location = aCharacter.Location;
                if (MousePos.X < aCharacter.Location.X)
                    lasDir = -1;
                else
                    lasDir = 1;
                laserLaunched = true;   
                return true;
            }

    private void aChMvmTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(laserLaunched)
        {
            aLaser.Location = new Point(aLaser.Location.X + lasDir, aLaser.Location.Y + (slope * lasDir));
            aLaser.Visible = true;

        }

        else
        {
            aLaser.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

However, it didn't shoot at the cursor and seemed almost random in where it shot. How would I go about doing this?

I tried another solution, though I doubt that I did it right.

```
  int currentTime = Environment.TickCount;
        double deltaTime = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000.0;
        lastTime = currentTime;
        if (laserLaunched)
        {

            int movementSpeed = 20;
            //aLaser.Location = new Point(aLaser.Location.X + lasDir, aLaser.Location.Y + (slope * lasDir));
            aLaser.Visible = true;
            double x = aLaser.Location.X - curMousePos.X;
            double y = aLaser.Location.Y - curMousePos.Y;
            double loc = ((int)x ^ 2) + ((int)y ^ 2);
            loc = Math.Sqrt(((int)x ^ 2) + ((int)y ^ 2));
            x = (x / (int)loc);
            y = (y / (int)loc);
            x *= (int)deltaTime * movementSpeed;
            y *= (int)deltaTime * movementSpeed;
            aLaser.Location = new Point(aLaser.Location.X + (int)x, aLaser.Location.Y + (int)y);
        }
```

Did I do it right?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a problem description.  And the qualifier "the slightest" does not improve upon it at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't realize that when I posted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use simple vector math:

Get a vector that points from A to B:

```
V = B - A // That means subtracting each component of B from the respective component of A.
```

If you were using `System.Windows.Point` instead of the WinForms version, you could use the `Point.Subtract(Point,Point)` method that gives you a `Vector` object as result right away.

Then normalize that vector, so you can better scale to the desired movement speed of the projectile. A normalized vector still has the same relative magnitude in each components, but a total length of 1. To achieve this, you divide each component by the total length of the vector or use `Vector.Normalize()` if you were using the `System.Windows` approach mentioned before.

Once you have the normalized vector, you can change the coordinates of your actual projectile position on every tick by the vector amount, multiplied by the desired speed and framerate of your tick event*.

Again, you can do this "by hand" or use the built-in functions of `Vector`:

```
newLocation = Vector.Add(Vector.Multiply(movementVector, movementSpeed * deltaTime), currentLocation);
```

---

*The `deltaTime` I used here can be acquired by storing the system time (in milliseconds) every time your tick function is called and comparing the current system time to that previous time. Divide it by 1000 and you get a floating point value that tells you the time difference in seconds, which then allows you to specify your projectile movement speed in "pixels per second". This makes the actual movement independent from the framerate that your tick function runs at, so it's not prone to become slower if the player's CPU is a bottleneck and also won't change if you decide to change the frequency of your tick updates for a smoother gameplay experience later on.

Example:

```
private int lastTime; // Initialize this to Environment.TickCount in your constructor.

private void TickUpdate() { // Called by your tick event.

    int currentTime = Environment.TickCount;
    double deltaTime = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000.0;
    lastTime = currentTime;

    // Do stuff with deltaTime.
}
```

Comment: That would make sense, but I'm not using WPF. How can I do it otherwise?

Comment: Well, you could still explicitly refer to Windows.Point in those places and use the coordinates of the end result in a Drawing.Point. Or you do all the stuff by hand, as I pointed out in the post. That means you just do all the operations on the X any Y components directly instead of using the convenience methods. So you take `B.X - A.X`, `B.Y - A.Y`, calculate the length of the resulting vector (`Sqrt(X^2+Y^2)`) and divide X and Y by that. Then you multiply X and Y by the movement speed and deltaTime and eventually add that to the respective X and Y of the old location.

Comment: That should work, though I am a bit inquisitive of how to go about deltaTime. Could you go a tad more in depth about how to acquire it? Thanks!

Comment: Added some example code for that. It's one of the basic concepts in video game development.

Comment: I edited the parent post to include the code that I interpreted. Is it correct? Because it didn't work in my code.

Comment: My code for calculating the length of a vector was just the formula, not actual code. You can't just write `x^2` and expect it to give you the squared value. You either use `Math.Pow(x, 2)` or simply `x*x`. The `^` operator in C# performs an XOR on two integers.